# Disabling click sound Android Studio

Tags: java, android, audio, click

I can't find in our segment of the Internet this decide.
I work on Android game, and I can't disable click sound on application level, when the user click on clickable elements: buttons, imageViews etc.

But I know that I can do this using smartphone menu, but this solution not good.

Then, how I can disable this sounds using android studio code?

Thanks for your all answers and your wasted time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just have to add this line off code to disable the sound

```
Button.setSoundEffectsEnabled(false);
```